# How to implement Google Sign-In with Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-signin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm begginer in Compose Multiplatform and I'm trying to implement Google Sing In **(whose objective is to get an `GoogleSignInAccount`object, to retrieve the `serverAuthCode` value)** with Compose Multiplatform.

Here is my UI code :

```
@Composable
fun MainActivity(colorScheme: ColorScheme, viewModel: MainActivityViewModel) {

    val context = getContext()
    val launcherManager = getLauncherManager()


    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable(
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                            launcherManager?.let {
                                AndroidGoogleSignInHandler(context, it.getActivityForResult {

                                }).signIn()
                            }
                        }

                    }
                )
                .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
                .padding(
                    start = 12.dp,
                    end = 16.dp,
                    top = 12.dp,
                    bottom = 12.dp
                )
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(40.dp)

        ) {
            /*
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_google_logo),
                contentDescription = "Google Login",
                tint = Color.Unspecified
            )

             */
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Sign in With Google"
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

The method `getLauncherManager()` is an `expect` method able to return (or not because of platform incompatibility) the function `registerForActivityResult`and looks like this
with `AndroidGoogleSignInHandler` and `ActivityResultLauncherManager` :

```
@Composable
expect fun getLauncherManager(): ActivityResultLauncherManager?

expect class AndroidGoogleSignInHandler(activity: Any?, signInLauncher: Any?) : GoogleSignInHandler {
    override fun signIn()
    override fun signOut()
}

expect class ActivityResultLauncherManager(activity: Any?) {
    fun getActivityForResult(callback: (Boolean) -> Unit): Any?
}
```

You can see that I'm using "Any" eveywhere because iOS doesn't have `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>` type for example

Here are implementation of `actual` functions inside **androidMain** :

```
actual interface GoogleSignInHandler {
    // Add other methods as needed
    actual fun signIn()
    actual fun signOut()
}

actual class AndroidGoogleSignInHandler actual constructor(val activity: Any?, val signInLauncher: Any?) : GoogleSignInHandler {
    private var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    init {
        // Initialize the GoogleSignInClient
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity as AppCompatActivity, gso)
    }

    actual override fun signIn() {
        if (activity is Context) {
            // Start the sign-in process
            val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            (signInLauncher as ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>).launch(signInIntent)
        } else {
            // Handle invalid activity parameter
        }
    }

    actual override fun signOut() {
        // Sign out from Google account
        googleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener { /* Handle sign out completion */ }
    }
}

@Composable
actual fun getContext(): Any? {
    return LocalContext.current
}

actual class ActivityResultLauncherManager actual constructor(val activity: Any?) {
    actual fun getActivityForResult(callback: (Boolean) -> Unit): Any? {
        return (activity as? AppCompatActivity)!!.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                val signInResult = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                val isSuccess = signInResult.isSuccessful

                callback(isSuccess)
            }
    }
}

@Composable
actual fun getLauncherManager(): ActivityResultLauncherManager? {
    val context = LocalContext.current as? AppCompatActivity
    return remember {
        ActivityResultLauncherManager(context!!)
    }
```

You can see in my code that I have a callback `callback: (Boolean) -> Unit`that had in parameter the success of the request (Boolean), but as I said in the top of the post, the goal will be to get the `serverAuthCode` value so I will replace "Boolean" with "String" if we find the solution ;)

So, in my UI, when I'm trying to call AndroidGoogleSignInHandler(...).signIn(), I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner xxx.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@7dabaee is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
```

So I think that I'm implementing `registerForActivityResult` too lately, but I'm don't know to deal with that because it's done by `expect` and `actual` keywords...

Is there a better way to implement GoogleSinIn with Compose Multiplatform ? I searched everywhere and I can't find a solution, except with KMM Jetpack Compose, so without Compose Multiplatform

One solution is to use a WebView, with a login page and this Google login button, then no problem ! But I don't want to deal with that if I can implement natively for both Android **AND** iOS. My code only deals with Android but if you have the solution for that...

Comment: if you managed to solve this on iOS as well please post your answer

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert your android code to be common.

But common code doesn't need to know how each platform does authentication, all it needs is a callback which should be called when button is pressed.

So you can move your platform implementation to a single composable. it can look something like this:

```
@Composable
actual fun rememberOnGoogleAuthAction(onTokenReceived: (String) -> Unit): () -> Unit {
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        onResult = { result ->
            val idToken = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                .getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                .idToken!!
            onTokenReceived(idToken)
        }
    )
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val client = remember {
        GoogleSignIn.getClient(
            context,
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken("clientId")
                .requestProfile()
                .build()
        )
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    return remember {
        {
            coroutineScope
                .launch {
                    client.signOut().await()
                    launcher.launch(client.signInIntent)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your common code call it like this:

```
.clickable(
    onClick = rememberOnGoogleAuthAction(viewModel::onTokenReceived)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying !
But as ```RememberOnGoogleAuthAction``` is a @Composable, it can't be called from ```onClick``` method... How to deal with that ? 
Furthermore, when I call this function outside onClick, I get this error : ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Launcher has not been initialized```
at ```launcher.launch(client.signInIntent)```

Comment: Well if I wrap like that : 
```LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        launcher.launch(client.signInIntent)

    }```
It's working, but I don't know how to call ```RememberOnGoogleAuthAction``` because it's @Composable and can't be launch inside onClick

Comment: @NathanaelHeitz it shouldn't be inside, my answer contains usage example

Comment: thanks ! My bad, I din't understood that it's a function that return a function ^^
I will try to find an example for IOS ! In Google doc it says that I must install dependency: ```GoogleSignIn```, but I don't see how can I call ```GIDSignIn``` inside ```rememberOnGoogleAuthAction``` on iOS side, is there a Kotlin equivalent ?

Comment: @NathanaelHeitz I don't think so. you need to install a pod, or create an interface, implement it on iOS side, then you could pass object created in iOS with custom [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) from the root view to be accessible in iOS version of `rememberOnGoogleAuthAction`

Comment: @NathanaelHeitz in case you implemented the solution for ios as well, it would be beneficial to provide the answer if possible as i am trying to achieve this as well